# How to compile & run a project-less file in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

> Netbeans, indeed any Java compiler and
>   executor, needs to know the classpath
>   to compile and run a file. When you
>   just open a file in Netbeans, you do
>   not tell it any of that information.
>   When you set up a project, that
>   process tells Netbeans where the Java
>   resources are.

Yet other IDEs can easily do this. It's not good practice, but it's simple and quick for "fooling around".

Is there any way to compile & run a file, that doesn't belong to a project, in Netbeans?

**edit:** The options are greyed out if the file doesn't belong to a project.

Comment: I think the problem is that NetBeans depends on Ant for everything. No ant file -> no compile or run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best option with NetBeans is just to create a dummy "try stuff" project that you know will never contain a shipping product but will allow you to experiment without having to create a new project every time.

You could even collect code snippets in different classes this way. If you add a `main()` method to each experimental class, you have a way to run them all in the IDE just by changing what you have set for the main project class. This is what I do and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using 'create new project with existing sources' which can be done for Java, Ruby, ... projects?

You can do so and netbeans will create only a nbproject folder within your project's dir and all should be fine.

Comment: not ideal if you only have one file as you need to select a directory with the source rather than a file

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't work great because projects are also "typed" and I work in 4 languages.  I'd hate to have a "rubystuff" project, a "pythonstuff" project, "javastuff", etc, etc...